# Lightbox v2 conflict with other JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox2

I have created a site for a friends portfolio, there is a javascript used to control the navigation, some jQuery used on the work section which swaps between 2 div's to show seperate categories, and then the Lightbox v2 viewer which should show the work he has done.

However, I have used lightbox before but I cannot seem to get it working on this website, could it be a conflict between the other javascript and jQuery loading on page load?

If anyone could take a look at the website and let me know what they think I would be very grateful.

My head has this for the lightbox (and other scripts)

```
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/lightbox.css"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="floating-1.5.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">  
 floatingMenu.add('floatdiv',  
    {   targetTop: 0,  
        // targetBottom: 0,    
        prohibitXMovement: true,});  
 </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
 }
 </script>
```

And my body for the lightbox:

```
 <div class="work_splash"><a href="images/gallery/graphics/1b.jpg" rel="lightbox[graphics]" title="Graphic Design Gallery"><img src="images/gallery/graphics/1t.jpg" height=156px /></a></div>
```

The URL is http://www.jrk-design.co.uk/barwise/index.html

Thanks

Jon

Comment: Your IMG tag is using the height attribute wrong. You should have `height="156"` or `style="height:156px;"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the order of the .js calls in the head or change the scriptaculous code for a jQuery script such as Pirobox

Comment: I have tried changing the .js calls, (by this you mean simply move the lightbox head tags after the other js head tags yes?) this did not seem to do anything.

Also, changed the viewer to Pirobox, no luck. 

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I created a responsive lightbox in javascript only which doesnt need jQuery. If you use jQuery just because of the lightbox plugin this maybe helps: http://jslightbox.felixhagspiel.de/

Answer (score 0):

Both Prototype and JQuery define `$`. Either get rid of one of the libraries or include jquery before Prototype as jonty john suggests or [use jquery in no-conflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Overriding_the_.24-function).

Comment: So I include 
     `jQuery.noConflict();`
in this piece of code:

      `<script type="text/javascript">
 function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
 $('div[name|="newboxes"]').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600);
      }
 });
 }
 </script>`

as that is at the end of my head code? Sorry, i'm more implementing this java as apposed to writing it (obviously), it's for a university presentation and I'm just trying to get it done for him! any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: You have to replace all your `$()` jquery calls with `jquery()` like `jquery(this).attr("id") ...`

Comment: Ok, so I have to do that on all `$()` calls on everything in my `<head>` tags? Or only on the bit above?

Comment: You have to do that to all jquery-calls, as is written on the page.